# On Localhost XML is Generating but in Server it's creating Empty Xml

Tags: php, xml, ubuntu, xslt

I'm using 'xsl' to generate the xml in the desired format, it's generating fine in the localhost, but if we generate the xml using server it's displaying empty page.

Comment: Is your hosting is dedicated or shared hosing? who is hosting provider?

Comment: Amazon and please solve my issue

Comment: Which OS is there? and specify version

Comment: [Fri Jul 22 13:32:53.291769 2016] [:error] [pid 7041] [client 106.51.126.175:53889] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'XSLTProcessor' not found in  This the error in ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Putty or SSH command connect with your Amazon Server.

Take Rights of Super user by below command

```
sudo -su root
```

Install php5-xsl package by below three command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xsl
sudo php5enmod xsl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I hope this would be help to you.

Thanks

Comment: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/php_xsl.dll' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/php_xsl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I'm getting this error